# Writing a Context Free Grammar for a language with multiple strings in the language

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

I have an interest in computing and want to learn more about the actual theory behind it. Context Free Grammar plays a part and I am quite fascinated by it all.

However, I came with a language that looks like this...
$\{a^{x + y} b^y c a^x | x, y \ge 0\}$

I have a CFG that looks like this...

```
S -> XY

X -> ab | a

Y -> cYa | ε
```

However, I believe it is incorrect, because there can only be one instance of c. How can I correct the CFG? How do you go about writing CFG's, especially this one -- so that I know or better understand how to write more complex ones

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here

Comment: @Harish, sorry, it is meant to be a^x+y all in one so a to the power (x+y)

Comment: is that right now?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Yes, it is :) thank you. I just don't know how to answer the question. My solution is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Have a non-terminal symbol $X$ that generates words of the form $a^mXa^m$ for $m\ge 0$ and then turns into $Yc$. Then have $Y$ generate words of the form $a^nb^n$ for $n\ge 0$. The end result will be words of the form $a^{m+n}b^nca^m$.

Comment: thanks, but what about the `b^n`? does that come in X or Y?

Comment: @Benjam: $Y$ generates words of the form $a^nb^n$, so it comes from the $Y$. These words are generated from the middle outwards.

Comment: okay thanks. so will Y look like `Y -> aYb` what about the `c` then?

Comment: @Benjam: The $c$ is produced by the $X$; you’ll have two different productions with $X$ on the lefthand side.

Comment: this is confusing now :S, sorry - I am just so lost now

Comment: @Benjam: You can use $S$ for $X$. Then you’ll have $S\to aSa\mid Yc$. If you apply the first production $m$ times and then the second, you’ll have $a^mYca^m$. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: im kind of understanding it now, so my initial answer was wrong? Can't I keep it in the S -> XY form?? X -> aXa | Y?

Comment: @Benjam: No, you can’t. You need to be sure that the number of initial $a$s is the same as the number of $b$s plus the number of final $a$s, which means that you should begin by generating the paired $a$s. Once that’s done, you need to drop off the $c$ and then generate the paired $a$s and $b$s. If you start with $S\to XY$, whatever $X$ generates will be completely independent of whatever $Y$ generates, so there will be no way to match up the numbers of $a$s.

Comment: I see. Thank you, so I guess it would have to start with S -> aSa | Y c? But what is `Y c`? Is that even legal? I thought it can only be `Y` OR `c` -- not both? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Benjam: It’s entirely legal. The only restriction on the productions of a context-free grammar is that the lefthand side be a single non-terminal symbol.

Comment: Bingo! I may have an answer then. Would `Y` be  `Y -> bY | ϵ`. Because what I am trying to say that there could more than one instance of `b`. Please tell me I am right, it would mean a lot? If not, please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Benjam: You’re on the right track, but you’re forgetting that $Y$ also has to generate an $a$ for each $b$; make that $Y\to aYb\mid\epsilon$, and you’ll be in business.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So let me try and understand what is happening here... you are saying that for every `b` there must be an `a`. But why? That is the only bit I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @Benjam: Because you need to get words of the form $a^{m+n}b^nca_m$. Say that after you generate $a^mYca^m$, you generate $n$ $b$s; then in order to get the right form of the word, you must also generate another $n$ $a$s over on the left. Remember, the number of $a$s at the front of the word must be exactly the number at the back **plus** the number of $b$s.

Comment: It is all making a lot of sense now :). So the final answer would be something like S -> aSa | Y c... Y -> aYb | ϵ?

Comment: @Benjam: Yes, those four productions will do the job just fine.

Comment: In any case, thank you for explaining it all to me. At least I now know `Y c` is legal

Comment: @Benjam: You’re welcome. If you have time at some point, you might browse some of the questions and answers with the [tag:context-free-grammar] tag; you might find something that increases your understanding. (Then again, you might find some very puzzling things. `:-)` There’s no telling.)